# What are the advantages of list view vs. grid view for video search results?

Tags: search, lists, grid, video

I'm designing a results page for video search for touch devices. on larger screens such as big tablets I'm considering using a grid views since it allows bigger thumbnails. I was wondering what the implications were.

Answer (score 1):

Grid views can indeed allow for bigger thumbnails - although not necessarily, as the height of a row on a list view could be the same height as a cell in a grid view.  The main differences, IMHO, are:

1. Grid view offers a *greater number of thumbnails* to the user, *at any one time*, than
   list view given the same screen real estate. This is because a list
   view will, typically, only have one column of thumbnails
   (accompanied by a description), whereas a grid view will, by
   definition, offer multiple columns.
2. List view can, typically, offer a *more detailed/lengthy description* (creation date, complete name, creator, etc.)
   accompanying the thumbnail than the descriptions in Grid views (which may only be able to offer a truncated name - depending on cell width).

There is no correct answer, it depends on what you want... or more correctly, what the user wants... and so, it is probably best to offer the user the choice of format that they wish to use to view their data, on screen.